# Question about Parameters in python functions

Tags: python, function, parameters

I've just begun trying my hand at Python and am a 100% beginner. I know for some this will be a really dumb question, but I'd really appreciate any help regarding this question.

So, in a function in Python, I know there has to be a parameter (the values in the parentheses) but my question is, what is the purpose of the parameter and how does it help define the function in the code.

Thanks in advance,
Yuvraj

[That's where I'm having my doubt][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7Ndt.png click link for image

Comment: I don't really get what you're saying:
If a function shall compute something based on parameters, then it obviously needs parameters. So `x` is just some variable that will receive the concrete value provided when the function is called. This value in turn is used for evaluation.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the help.

Comment: Basic idea: All external values you need in the function should be provided by parameters and values leave the function with the `return` statement. For the sake of flexibility and reusability never rely on variable names from the outer scope.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is completely general and is not related just to python.
Functions are created for the two most principal reasons:

1- to avoid writing repetitious codes. for example, consider you want to write a code in order to calculate the sum of two numbers (very simply) you have two ways to do that :

1-1 write summation operation everywhere of the code which you need to calculate the  summation

1-2 write a function which gives two numbers as parameters and returns the sum of them, and just call it everywhere you need to find the summation.
obviously, the second way is more efficient and nicer than the first way.

2- To make your code clean and more readable.

When you're defining a function it is not necessary to define parameters for it and it depends on what you're trying to do. if you want to run your function every time for new kind of data so you have to define parameters (arguments) for it and use them in the function. Let's go back to my example, consider you want to write a function to calculate the sum of two numbers and returns it, this is how it looks like:

```
def summation(first_number, second_number):
    return first_number + second_number
```

overall, you can do whatever you want with the passed parameter in your function, and it depends on your task.
 be lucky :-)

Answer (score 0):

parameters are the values you perform function upon. This is as simple as it can get.

Answer (score 0):

As in the example you showed, the `def subtract(x, y):` allows the x and the y a value of when it is called upon. So we can call the function by typing `subtract(3, 2)` and the output will `return` x - y, or in our case, 3 - 2. Hope this helps!